# What is the official personal trainer certification and how to get a certification?

Tags: training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which personal trainer certifications are most respected?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/which-personal-trainer-certifications-are-most-respected)

Could anyone please me some information?

Thanks

Comment: Please check out the information in [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/which-personal-trainer-certifications-are-most-respected) (which also happens to be closed).

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here. There are a lot of certifications and they vary by country. Without additional information, I'm afraid users are only left guessing how they can help you. I closed as a duplicate because hopefully the linked answer can provide a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should follow the PTaGlobal courses. These are VERY good courses and are internationally known in the fitness industry.

http://www.ptaglobal.com/